# Split text into new line if text exceeds the device width

Tags: android, textview

How to split the text to new line if text is larger than the device width?

For eg.

aaaaa bbbbbbbb
bbbb

Expected Output-
aaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb

Comment: What you want is a normal TextView behavior

Comment: If you use Textview ,larger text come next

Comment: use " \n " to split between the lines

Comment: if text is greater than device width than only i want  that particular word to be on next line  else not

Comment: use match_parent for the textView

Comment: @IntelliJShivam: It's not automatically splitting

Comment: the whole last would come in next line if.. its not fit in that..!!

Comment: @IntelliJShivam:match_parent is not working

Comment: @Ragini : can you share the screenshot of it..!

Comment: Please share screenshot of your layout

Answer (score 2):

Just use "\n" where ever you want to split the text.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution is working -

```
txtUserName.post(new Runnable()
            {  
                @Override  
                public void run()
                {

                    int textviewWidth = getTextviewWidth(text, getWidthOfScreen());

                    int deviceWidth = getWidthOfScreen();

                    if (textviewWidth >= deviceWidth)
                    {

                        String userName = text.replace(" ", "\n");

                        txtUserName.setText(userName);
                    }
                }
            });


public int getTextviewWidth(String text, int deviceWidth)
    {

        txtUserName.setText(text);
        int widthMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(deviceWidth, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        int heightMeasureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        txtUserName.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        return txtUserName.getMeasuredWidth();
    }

 public int getWidthOfScreen()
    {

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        (mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        return width;

    }
```